# Selecting array values from an array of indexes

Tags: php, arrays

Got this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [correct] => 
                    [answer] => false answer1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [correct] => 
                    [answer] => false answer2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [correct] => 
                    [answer] => false answer3
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [correct] => 1
                    [answer] => correct answer
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [correct] => 
                    [answer] => false answer1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [correct] => 
                    [answer] => false answer2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [correct] => 
                    [answer] => false answer3
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [correct] => 1
                    [answer] => correct answer
                )

        )
)
```

and got an array of indexes:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )
)
```

The output that i would like to get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [correct] => 
                    [answer] => false answer1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [correct] => 
                    [answer] => false answer2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [correct] => 
                    [answer] => false answer3
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [correct] => 
                    [answer] => false answer1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [correct] => 
                    [answer] => false answer2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [correct] => 
                    [answer] => false answer3
                )

        )
)
```

As you can see, i want to select all the values from the 1st array, depending on the indexes of the 2nd array. How do i do that?

Edit:

heres how im trying to solve it now:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++){
    $output_array[] = $array1[$i][$index_array[$i][0]];
    $output_array[] = $array1[$i][$index_array[$i][1]];
    $output_array[] = $array1[$i][$index_array[$i][2]];
}
```

output is not what i want at all..

Edit2:

Tried something like this:

```
$output_array[$i] = array_push($array1[$i][$index_array[$i][1]]);
$output_array[$i] = array_push($array1[$i][$index_array[$i][2]]);
```

but didnt work..

Comment: Usually it is done after having some training with arrays for yourself. Just play around with it rather than asking such localized questions (don't take it personal ;)

Comment: SO is not for getting people to write code for you, you have to make some effort first. Show what you've tried, and we'll help you fix the problems.

Comment: I tried using `foreach` and `for` loops, ill edit op with what im trying atm..

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++){
    $output_array[$i][] = $array1[$i][$index_array[$i][0]];
    $output_array[$i][] = array_merge($array1[$i][$index_array[$i][1]]);
    $output_array[$i][] = array_merge($array1[$i][$index_array[$i][2]]);
}
```

Not sure if its the correct way, but it works..